# Lime plaster in Mumbai India - pros and cons?

Tags: plaster

I live in Mumbai India, in an old building. I don't know how long it is, but at least a century old, I would estimate. There is plaster deterioration in various parts of the structure. I'm done plaster work in some places, but more remains to be done.

I'm told that lime plaster used to be in general use in India, but is not longer used, cement plaster being used instead. But also that lime plaster is generally considered superior.

It seems that it would be quite difficult to find someone to do lime plastering work locally. But let's assume that I will be able to do so. Are the benefits significant? And what are the pros and cons? Is it worth going to significant trouble to use lime plaster instead of cement plaster?

I'm looking for answers from people with first hand experience working with these different kinds of plaster.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lime_plaster#Advantages, http://www.diyplastering.co.uk/limeplasterbenefits.html, https://www.buildinglimesforum.org.uk/why-use-lime etc.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Sure, but I wanted actual first hand information. I've no idea who wrote those web pages. The last one in particular reads like an ad.

Comment: Will the plaster be exposed to the elements?

Comment: @tahwos In some cases, yes. Heavy rain and intense sunlight. Not at the same time, of course.